# PostgreSQL 9.3: pg_dump fails due to tiger.direction_lookup

Tags: postgresql-9.3, postgis, aws, pg-dump, amazon-rds

I am trying to dump the schema from one of my PostgreSQL 9.3+PostGIS databases:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_dump --schema-only 
                                    -h stg-db.....rds.amazonaws.com 
                                    -U user_name db_name > stg_db_schema.sql
```

The command works well on my dev db, but fails on stg and prod due to:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation direction_lookup
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE tiger.direction_lookup IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

The problem seems to be permissions for `tiger.direction_lookup`. I Googled a bit, and this table seems to be related to PostGIS.

I have tried `--exclude-table-data=tiger.direction_lookup`, with no effect (it is not supposed to work for schemas anyway).

Any idea how to be able to dump the schema of my DB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that I had to re-run the [AWS RDS PostGIS instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.PostGIS):

```
CREATE FUNCTION exec(text) returns text language plpgsql volatile AS $f$ BEGIN EXECUTE $1; RETURN $1; END; $f$;
SELECT exec('ALTER TABLE ' || quote_ident(s.nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(s.relname) || ' OWNER TO rds_superuser')
  FROM (
    SELECT nspname, relname
    FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace n ON (c.relnamespace = n.oid) 
    WHERE nspname in ('tiger','topology') AND
    relkind IN ('r','S','v') ORDER BY relkind = 'S')
s;
```

This is clearly an RDS Bug, because these instructions should not be executed more than once.

Perhaps this happened due to a database minor version upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Adam, your answer was little confusing, but it did drive me to right direction. so this alter statement help me create dump. > ALTER TABLE tiger.direction_lookup OWNER TO rds_superuser;